# Combining dataframes of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes, where one is an extended version of another. (1) How do I combine the two efficiently based on if the two dataframes share the same Name? (2) also is there a way to add in four spaces for code in the stackoverflow box without typing in four spaces for each line? That can be time consuming.

**more details**

One is a full dataframe with multiple listings of a value (sortedregsubjdf). the other contains only unique values of that other dataframe (as it is a dataframe of network centralities) - called sortedcentralitydf

**sortedregsubjdf**

```
Name    Organization    Year    Centrality
 6363    (Buz) Business And Commerce     doclist[524]    2012    0.503677
 8383    (Buz) Business And Commerce     doclist[697]    2012    0.503677
 1170    (Buz) Business And Commerce     doclist[103]    2012    0.503677
 1579    (Eco) Economics News    doclist[140]    2013    0.500624
 10979   (Gop) Provincial Government News    doclist[941]    2013    0.501232
 4374    (Gop) Provincial Government News    doclist[368]    2013    0.501232
 10988   (Npt) Not-For-Profits   doclist[942]    2013    0.498810
```

**sortedcentralitiesdf** (business and commerce only appears once since it contains unique values, where sortedregsubjdf has multiple values)

```
 Name   Centrality
 316     (Buz) Business And Commerce     0.503677
 448     (Eco) Economics News    0.500624
 499     (Gop) Provincial Government News    0.501232
 366     (Npt) Not-For-Profits   0.498810
 217     (Pdt) New Products And Services     0.504600
```

This was my code to combine the two dataframes, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do so?

```
for i, val in enumerate(sortedcentralitydf.Name):
    for x, xval in enumerate(sortedregsubjdf.Name):
        if val == xval:
        #print val, xval
            sortedregsubjdf.Centrality[sortedregsubjdf.Name == xval] =   sortedcentralitydf.Centrality[sortedcentralitydf.Name == val].iloc[0]
```

Comment: There is a code sample symbol `{ }` that you can use for formatting code.  Also, it looks like you have a large number of questions without accepted answers.  Accepting answers is a way of saying thanks to those who help you and indicating to future readers which solutions effectively solve a problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris. New to stackoverflow. I just accepted a bunch of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a `merge` function. It sounds like something like this would work...

```
import pandas as pd
merged_df = pd.merge(sortedregsubjdf, sortedcentralitiesdf, on='Name')
```